# Power automate flow with Price condition (greater than $1000)

Tags: power-automate

I am having a challenge in solving the power automate flow condition.
I want to achieve this - *if the price is greater than $1000 > the flow will go to next Lv3 approver , else it will stop at level2 approver.*

the *"Total"* is a calculated value of *"Quantity"* and *"price"*.
I am seeking an expert's advice in this.

Thank you.

this is  my flow and error.
[image]

[image]

Comment: The error says you're comparing a string to an integer. Probably need to look at the passed-in value, which currently seems to be a string (and you'd need to convert that, for any type of numeric comparison)

Comment: thanks alot. @DavidMakogon  it works after initialized the variable and pass int(outputs('Get_item')?['body/Total'])